# I met a question when using boost::serialization, my code works fine in linux, but met a exception in windows

Tags: c++, boost, slam

I am trying to save a map build by ORB-SLAM using boost, the code works fine in linux, but when I move it to windows, I met the exception when load data. Below is part of my code, it's a big project, so I just show the related code.

Some of the code in .h

```
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, version);
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const;


    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);
```

CPP profile

```
        template<class Archive>
        void Map::load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
        unsigned int test_data;

        int nItems;
        ar & nItems;
        cout << "{INFO}mspMapPoints size = " << nItems << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i) {

            MapPoint* pMapPoint = new MapPoint();
            ar & *pMapPoint;
            mspMapPoints.insert(pMapPoint);
        }

        ar & nItems;
        cout << "{INFO}mspKeyFrames size = " << nItems << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i) {

            KeyFrame* pKeyFrame = new KeyFrame;
            ar & *pKeyFrame;
            mspKeyFrames.insert(pKeyFrame);
        }     


        ar & nItems;
        cout << "{INFO}mvpKeyFrameOrigins size = " << nItems << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i) {             

            KeyFrame* pKeyFrame = new KeyFrame;
            ar & *pKeyFrame;
            /* TODO : VerifyHere*/
            mvpKeyFrameOrigins.push_back(*mspKeyFrames.begin());
        }     

        ar & const_cast<long unsigned int &> (mnMaxKFid);

        ar & test_data;
        if (test_data == TEST_DATA)
            cout <<">>Map Loading Validated as True" << endl;
        else
            cout <<"ERROR Map Loading Validated as False: Got -" << test_data << " :( Check Load Save sequence" << endl;

    }
```

The call function is as follows:

```
void System::LoadMap(const string &filename)
{
    {
        std::ifstream is(filename,std::ios::binary);


        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is, boost::archive::no_header);
        //ia >> mpKeyFrameDatabase;
        ia >> mpMap;

    }

    cout << endl << filename <<" : Map Loaded!" << endl;


}
void System::SaveMap(const string &filename)
{
    std::ofstream os(filename,std::ios::binary);
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os, boost::archive::no_header);
        //oa << mpKeyFrameDatabase;
        oa << mpMap;
    }
    cout << endl << "Map saved to " << filename << endl;

}
```

It's ok both save and load in Linux,but load will just throw boost::archive::archive_exception problem ,didn't tell me any details.

Answer (score 1):

You should show relevant code only. In particular, it should show your archive choice. Also, you never told us /what/ doesn't work, but my guess is that you're loading an archive saved on the linux side on the windows side?

The binary archive format is not portable. So by all means, avoid that or use a dropin replacement that tries to be portable: https://github.com/mika-fischer/eos-portable-archive

Comment: Thanks for your help!But it didn't tell me the detail problem,just  boost::archive::archive_exception,and both the map is saved and loaded on windows.I do save it as binary archive format,I will try other format.Thank you very much!